# Do I need to call verifyIdToken() when using custom claims in callable functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

The documentation on [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#backend_implementation_admin_sdk) says ID tokens should be verified on every call, but the documentation for [callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) says the tokens are automatically verified.

I assume the custom claims documentation referers to "non-callable" functions, but it still is rather confusing.

If the tokens are automatically verified, are they also checked for being revoked like when calling `admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken, true)`?

Comment: verifyIdToken *is* the way that callable functions internally work to provide auth info in the context.

Comment: Thanks Doug! That's all I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to verify token yourself when using callable function which automatically verifies the auth token. The `context.auth.token` is the `DecodedIdToken` object which contains all of user's custom claims.

```
// Saves a message to the Firebase Realtime Database but sanitizes the text by removing swearwords.
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    return { error: "No User" }
  }

  console.log(context.auth.token);
});
```